# What counts as a 'valid http response' for testing an NLS server?

Tags: direct-access

[Direct Access detects you are inside](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff641736.aspx) the network by making an SSL connection to a system within your network.  The steps to validate include resolving the name, making an https connect, validating the certificate, and CRL.

From the linked Microsoft doc.

> If the client can access the network location URL successfully over SSL and receive a valid HTTP response indicating a successful connection,

What I specifically want to know is **what counts as a valid http response?**  Does the response need to be an HTTP 200?  Can I configure a server that is available both internally and externally and have it work if my server returns a HTTP 200 for internal clients, and a 403 for external clients?  Or does any valid HTTP reply count as successful, so long as it is HTTP?

Or to put it differently, can I use IP address based ACLs on my main web server,  so I can avoid having to maintain a separate server inside my network?

Answer (score 0):

It must be a 200 OK. The web server must not be reachable externally. If you don't want to use a dedicated web server, you can create a new web site on an existing internal web server. Obviously that would require a dedicated IP address, but you could SNI instead. You can also host the NLS on a load balancer (NetScaler, F5, Kemp all support it) if you don't want to use a web server at all.